# PHP Class Referring PDO Object

Tags: php, pdo

I am creating 2 Class and from 1 class I am referring the other class a PDO Object. But when I refer any string of that class, but not when PDO Object. Any ideas?
Here is my code

```
class Connection
    {
        private $dbcc;
        public function Fn_Db_Conn()
        {
            $this->dbcc = new  PDO( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1;",
             "root","pass1");
            return $this->dbcc;
        }
    }
    class Registration
    {
        private $Username;
        private $dbc;
        public function Registration($Un)
        {
            $this->Username = $Un;
            $this->dbc = new Connection;
            $this->dbc->Fn_Db_Conn();
        }
        public function Fn_User_Exist()
        {

            $Qry = "SELECT * FROM CMT_Users WHERE Username=@Username";
            $Result = $this->dbc->prepare($Qry);
            $Result->bindParam("@Username",$this->Username);
            $Result->execute();
            print $Result->rowCount();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Connection
{
    private $_dbcc;
    public function getConnection()
    {
       return $this->_dbcc;
    }
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_dbcc = new  PDO( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1;",
             "root","pass1");
    }
}
class Registration
{
    private $_username;
    private $_dbc;


    public function __construct($un)
    {
        $this->_username = $un;
        $this->_dbc = new Connection();
    }
    public function Fn_User_Exist()
    {

        $qry = "SELECT * FROM CMT_Users WHERE Username=@Username";
        $result = $this->_dbc->getConnection()->prepare($qry);
        $result->bindParam("@Username",$this->_username);
        $result->execute();
        print $result->rowCount();
    }
}
```

I have also modified the Connection class to create the PDO object in the constructor and added a getConnection method for accessing the PDO object.

You should use the `__construct` keyword for constructor, naming the constructor as the class name is the old syntax and make the code more difficult to edit.

Last point, it depends on people but I prefer to prepend protected and private properties or methods by an underscore `_`, this way we can identify easily if the method/property is accessible outside of the class or not. You should aboid using variable like `Result` because PHP is case sensitive so `Result` is not equal to `result`, so better to avoid typo to keep the variable name in lower case(appart when you want to do camelCase).

Comment: Thanks, it s solved, and again thanks for those suggesstions.